# Write out pre-order, in-order, and post-order traversals given a tree:

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

Okay, so given this tree I need to write out the pre-order, in-order, and post-order traversals for it.

```
                                     9
                                  /     \
                                 5       12
                                / \     /  \
                               2   7   11   15
                              /   /   /  \    \
                             3   6   10  13    16
                                                 \
                                                  17
```

This is what I've come up with, my teacher didn't do a great job of going over this so I'm not sure if I'm anywhere near correct.

```
       pre-order: 9 5 2 3 7 6 12 11 10 13 15 16 17
       in-order: 3 2 5 7 6 9 12 11 10 13 15 16 17
       post-order: 3 2 6 7 5 10 11 17 16 15 13 12 9
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: we need program or how this output come?

Comment: what is your question? why is it tagged as "python"?

Comment: we do not need to program. i was given the tree and used wikipedia to help build the pre-order, in-order, and post-order outputs above. I just wanna know if I'm doing it right

Comment: There is plenty of code available online performing this task, it should be trivial to modify it to run on this tree, [like I did here](http://ideone.com/bBf7YF).

Comment: A good sanity check is to verify:  pre-order: root is the first in the list of nodes traversed; in-order: root is in the middle of the nodes traversed; post-order:  root is the last in the list of nodes traversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pre-order**: Do a depth-first traveral and write out the node when you encounter it the first time. So this is correct (9 5 2 3 7 6 12 11 10 13 15 16 17).

**Post-order**: Do a depth-first traversal and write out the node after you have processed all its children. So the correct sequence would be (3 2 6 7 5 10 13 11 17 16 15 12 9).

**In-order**: Do a depth-first traversal and write out the left subtree first, then the node itself and afterwards the right subtree. So the correct sequence would be (3 2 5 6 7 9 10 11 13 12 15 16 17). Here it makes a difference whether a single child is the left or right, for the other methods it doesn't matter.